# Styled-Components and Template Literals

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components

Can someone help explain how does this `` styled.a`aasdasd` ``   Works? Is this valid JS ?? and what does it mean? This is a code snippet from  `styled-components` Library?

```
const Button = styled.a`
  /* This renders the buttons above... Edit me! */
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  margin: 0.5rem 1rem;
  width: 11rem;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid white;

  /* The GitHub button is a primary button
   * edit this to target it specifically! */
  ${props => props.primary && css`
    background: white;
    color: black;
  `}
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the javascript **tagged templates** documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates

Comment: That answers it ✅ Thanks.